# Do we need to import YUI scripts for all pages?

Tags: yui, javascript

I have a number of list pages and all pages have YUI datatables with menu bar in the page.

If i select a menu item, the corresponding list page will be displayed.

My question is: do we need to import the scripts for all pages, even though the same scripts are used for menu bar?

When I debug the list page from browser it is showing menu bar scripts as well as list page scripts. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [YUI Loader.](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuiloader/)